# How to set cell format always in negative in specific column?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I would like to make a simple tracking sheet for onhand stock Qty. Column F is the actual stock Qty will sum up all row cell value. the column incl. "export" (e.g. column H & J.) should be a negative value.

I have tried the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim isect As Range
Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("I:I"))
If Not (isect Is Nothing) Then
    If Target.Value > 0 Then Target.Value = 0 - Target.Value
End If

End Sub
```

it will turn the column "I" to negative automatically. However, I will add more batches in the future. Is any way automatically turn negative if the column contains "export"?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick. just check if the value of row 2 in target column is "Export"
(Assuming it is row 2)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim isect As Range
Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, Range("G3:Z5000"))
If Not (isect Is Nothing) Then
    If Cells(2, Target.Column).Value = "export" Then
        If Target.Value > 0 Then
            Target.Value = 0 - Target.Value
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

If you have no other way of ensuring the values below "export" are negative (e.g excel-formulas) then use this modified code of yours.

```
Option Explicit
Public EventsEnabled As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If EventsEnabled Then
    EventsEnabled = False

    Dim isect As Range
    Dim exportRange As Range

    Set exportRange = GetExportRange()
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(Target, exportRange)
    If Not (isect Is Nothing) Then
        If Target.Value > 0 Then Target.Value = 0 - Target.Value
    End If

    EventsEnabled = True
End If
End Sub

Function GetExportRange() As Range ' get all columns were the first 3 rows contain "export"
Dim srchrng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim exprng As Range
Dim cletter As String

Set srchrng = Range("J1:XFD3") ' modify here for other search range

Set exprng = Range("I:I")
For Each cell In srchrng
    If cell.Value = "export" Then
        cletter = Split(Cells(1, cell.Column).Address, "$")(1) ' get the letter from the address
        Set exprng = Union(exprng, Range(cletter & ":" & cletter))
    End If
Next cell

Set GetExportRange = exprng
End Function
```

This should be working fine. For performance reasons you should think about disabling events after the `_Change` event and enabling it when you finish. You see if the `_Change` event changes something another `_Change` event will be triggered. So you can change things while you change things. Therefore I suggested the `EnableEvents` boolean. I have used the `Application.EnableEvents` but for reasons I do not remember I stopped doing that and used a public boolean instead.